# Angular2 computed filtered list

Tags: angular

I have an array with social connections for a connected customer. I have 3 different segments in my app where I show Invited connections, Existing Connections and NonInvited/NonRegistered connections.

I am trying to use computed properties to make my life easier.

component segment

```
export class SocialComponent implements OnInit {
    public loaded = false;
    public connections:Connection[] = [];

    constructor(public socialService:SocialService) {
    }

    loadConnections() {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            self.socialService
                .connections()
                .subscribe(connections => {
                    self.connections = connections;
                    resolve(connections);
                }, error => reject(error));
        });
    }

    public get registeredConnections():Connection[] {
        return this.connections.filter(connection => {
            return connection.exists;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var promises = [];

        promises.push(this.loadConnections());
        //..... 
        //other promises here
        //.....

        Promise.all(promises).then(values => this.loaded = true);
    }
}
```

Template

```
<div class="well">
    <h4>People you know that are coming</h4>
    {{ registeredConnections | json }}
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="#connection of registeredConnections">
        <connection [connection]="connection"></connection>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use the `{{ registeredConnections | json }}` on its own it all works fine.

The second i try the ngFor, ngIf I get the following error

```
EXCEPTION: Expression 'registeredConnections in SocialComponent@5:34' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '' in [registeredConnections in SocialComponent@5:34]
```

Comment: A little search [throws these results](https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=has+changed+after+it+was+checked&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in dev mode, angular will check your bindings twice to make sure they're not changing.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6006

Try changing registeredConnections from an auto-computed property to a regular property. Then call a function to populate the array:

```
export class SocialComponent implements OnInit {
    public loaded = false;
    public connections:Connection[] = [];
    public registeredConnections: Connection[];
    loadConnections() {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            self.socialService
                .connections()
                .subscribe(connections => {
                    self.connections = connections;
                    self.registeredConnections = connections.filter(connection => { return connection.exists; });

                    resolve(connections);
                }, error => reject(error));
        });
    }
```

Comment: yes that works fine, but makes my business logic a mess. Anyway both enabling production mode and this work!